# Does Analytics for Web (analytics.js) work for Hybrid Apps like Ionic-Meteor

Tags: meteor, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, angular-meteor

I am using Analytics for Web (analytics.js) in my Hybrid app which is in Angular-Ionic Meteor. This was working great with [My Website](https://dev.goodatlas.com) but from my Mobile it's not working.

[Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/?authuser=1#the_javascript_tracking_snippet)

Is this thing working with my native app or this analytics only work for Websites?

If this thing only for websites than which Meteor Analytics Package is best suitable for my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using  this plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-segment

You just need to install it and then you make the same use as you did for the website.

I hope it helps ;)